# HTML iframe allow autoplay of audio file not working safari

Tags: html, browser, safari

This works perfect with other browsers but safari automatically downloads file.

```
<iframe src="lib/audio/voice.mp3" allow="autoplay" class="audio-main" id="iframeAudio">
</iframe>
```

I need play background audio in a website. Opera and Chrome are working fine unfortunatelly Safari Browser open website automatically audio download.What exactly is the problem, Thanks for advance

Comment: It is always a good idea to start a question with your problem, then explain what you have tried to resolve it and finally conclude with what you expected to find. Try and include as much information as possible. Which browsers are working? What do they do with the file? Is there any other JavaScript libraries in use like a player perhaps? Where did you get this code? The more information you can give the easier it is to attract someone knowledgeable with answers.

Comment: I need play background audio in a website. Opera and Chrome are working fine unfortunatelly Safari Browser open website automatically audio download.

Comment: I suggest edit your question to improve it based on the suggestions. Users tend to ignore negative scored questions but there is nothing wrong with your questions you just need to follow the conventions.

Answer (score 3):

## No Auto-Play by default says the man

According to [Safari / WebKit Auto-Play policy](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) it gives users the ability to browse the web with fewer distractions, particularly in the form of relief from websites that auto-play with sound. They instruct websites to assume that any use of video or audio will require a user gesture or click to play.

## Policy configuration

Users can enable auto play functionality on a per website bases.

> Safari >> Preferences >> Websites >> Auto-Play

**Options are:**

- Allow All Auto-Play
- Stop Media with Sound (default)
- Never Auto-Play

## Functionality iframe allow autoplay works in Safari

When the user has allowed auto play from a specific website the `iframe` tag works as expected.

```
<iframe allow="autoplay" src="happy.mp3"></iframe>
```

Not surprising though so too does the `<audio>` element load and play on its own.

```
<audio autoplay loop src="happy.mp3"></audio>
```

## Detect auto play is disabled and display player

However it should be expected that this functionality will not be enabled, since the ability exists for users to disable it, so it’s important to detect if auto play was denied and proactively react accordingly.

```
var promise = $('video')[0].play();

if (promise) promise.catch(error => {
    // Auto-play disabled show controls 
    $('audio').attr('controls', '');
});
```

For this option we do not need auto play at all since we are manually calling play. This will not work of course if a user action is required so all we are left to do is to add the controls and display the player.

## Audio with controls

For the sake of completion, there's always the other option; avoid auto play all together... but what's the fun in that.

```
<audio controls src="happy.mp3"></audio>
```

nJoy!